# Setting special characters in INPUT element that are not executing javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xss

I have the issue that I want to allow special characters (in an encoded fashion) to be used in input but prevent XSS. I don't seem to have this problem when when I directly set the html attribute (e.g. by doing .html("my value") using jquery), but the issue happens when I use elements without closing tags like INPUT.

This is my scenario:

Dynamic client web service request using ajax, so I can't use some kind of inline code to build the page. This happens after the base page is loaded:

```
    var data = {
        "key": "value"
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/GetData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function callFunction(result) {
            if (result.d != null) {
                // Building an HTML block
                var preBuiltHtml = "<table style=\"width:100%;\">" +
                    "<tr>" +
                        "<td>Entry 1:</td>" +
                        "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtEntry1\" maxlength=\"100\" value=\"" + result.d.return_value + "\" style=\"width:100%;\" ></td>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                "</table>";
                $('#someDialog').html(preBuiltHtml);
            }
            else {
                showMessageDialog("Permission denied", 1);
            }
        },
        error: function () { showMessageDialog('Error!', 2); }
    });
```

Server side (ASP.NET) with character encoding to prevent XSS:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public SomeClass GetProjectDetails(string proj_nr)
{
    SomeClass result = new SomeClass();
    result.return_value = Encoder.HtmlEncode("<IMG SRC=\"javascript: alert('XSS');\">");
    return result;
}
```

On the client side, this will fill in the input element properly, but the javascript is executed. If I use the jquery .val() method to set the value, it completely messes up the html for the element. If I set the same value to a div using .html(), everything is fine, but I can't do that to an input element.

What would be the right way to set this kind of value without it being executed on client side?

Thanks a lot in advance

Edit: One more thing, the alert box is not executed as you might expect, so no message box shows up. But looking at the network tab in the dev mode of Chrome, you can see an entry:
[image]

Edit 2: String retrieved from web service
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering user input you should be setting the value rather than inlining the HTML, something like:

```
var preBuiltHtml = "<table style=\"width:100%;\">" +
  "<tr>" +
    "<td>Entry 1:</td>" +
    "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtEntry1\" maxlength=\"100\" style=\"width:100%;\" ></td>" +
  "</tr>" +
"</table>";

var input = $('#someDialog').html(preBuiltHtml).find('#txtEntry1');
input.val(result.d.return_value);
```

You said that *"it completely messes up the html for the element"* could you be more specific?

If I try this directly it works as expected...

```js
var unescaped = '<IMG SRC="javascript: alert(\'XSS\');">';
var escaped = '&lt;IMG&#32;SRC=&quot;javascript: alert(&#39;XSS&#39;);&quot;&gt;'

// Escaped content is still escaped
var input1 = document.querySelector('#test1');
input1.value = escaped;
 
// Unescaped content is preserved
var input2 = document.querySelector('#test2');
input2.value = unescaped;

// HTML should use the escaped version
var div3 = document.querySelector('#test3');
div3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" value="' + escaped + '">'
```

```html
<input id=test1>

<input id=test2>

<div id=test3></div>
```

The error in the network tab is because you used `<IMG SRC` which won't execute inline javascript but will try to retrieve it (exactly as if you had done `<IMG SRC="javascript.png">`).

Comment: OK maybe I mixed up some other issue, when using .val(), the input field simply stays empty and the entry in the network tab happens too. FYI the encoded value I get from the web server looks as added in the latest edit of my starting post.

Comment: @vm370 so do you want to see that literal string in the input box? If you set `input.val('<img>')` I wouldn't expect to see anything, as there's no plain text to show.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the input2 seems to be what I'm looking for. The escaping you show is only on client side then, I guess I should do that on server side instead of the HtmlEncode method? Somehow I always feel that there's something missing when I do the escaping manually (e.g. replacing certain special characters). Is there a definitive list of all characters that need to be escaped when setting it as a value for an input element?

Comment: @vm370 If you're going to echo the content direct from the server then escape on the server. If you're going to use it programmatically (such as using the `.val()` or `.text()` jQuery functions) then JS will be escaping for you and the server doesn't need to. I find it's easiest to pick one or the other and do it consistently.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131060/discussion-between-vm370-and-keith).

Comment: Sorry but I have to remove the answered flag from this since your solution unfortunately doesn't prevent the execution of javascript. Also it seems that programmatically setting a value e.g. using .val() doesn't change the string in any way.

Comment: @vm370 which solution?

Comment: Sorry again, turns out I missed another part of my script. You were right all along. Re-flagged.